# How do I tell between FAT16 and FAT32 USB? (Windows)

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, fat32, fat16

How can I tell if my USB stick is formatted as FAT16?

Windows 7 Disk Management says that my USB stick is a FAT volume. But it doesn't say whether it's FAT16 or FAT32. I opened the Property window and it doesn't tell between FAT16 and FAT32 either.

Comment: If it's over 4 GB, it can't be FAT16.

Comment: If you go to an elevated command line, run `diskpart` and then type `list volume`, it should tell you the file system that any attached drive is using. Be sure not to change anything with this tool if you don't know what you're doing, or you'll be a sad camper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the drive just says FAT and does not say that it's FAT16, FAT32 or NTFS, that means that the drive is formatted as FAT16.

[Source](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/182071en)

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If it is over 2 GB then it is FAT32. FAT has a file and partition limit of 2 GB.

There are ways to make a 4 GB flash into 2 x 2 GB FAT partitions, but usually older cameras requiring FAT will only be able to 'see' the first partition.

Comment: If it is below 2 GB it can either one. It could be FAT32.

Comment: FAT16 can be used on a 4GB partition]

Answer (score -1):

Normally that would be FAT 32.You can check that in disk management screen.

Comment: "Normally that would be FAT 32" - What's the source for this? The other answer's source seems valid.